# Webrtc2sip: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, webrtc

I am trying to compile following code `webrtc2sip` but getting following error.

```
root@dev1:/usr/local/src/webrtc2sip# g++  -g -O2   -o webrtc2sip webrtc2sip-mp_c2c.o webrtc2sip-mp_engine.o webrtc2sip-mp_mail.o webrtc2sip-mp_mediaproxy.o webrtc2sip-mp_mutex.o webrtc2sip-mp_net_transport.o webrtc2sip-mp_object.o webrtc2sip-mp_peer.o webrtc2sip-mp_proxyplugin.o webrtc2sip-mp_proxyplugin_consumer_audio.o webrtc2sip-mp_proxyplugin_consumer_video.o webrtc2sip-mp_proxyplugin_mgr.o webrtc2sip-mp_proxyplugin_producer_audio.o webrtc2sip-mp_proxyplugin_producer_video.o webrtc2sip-mp_session.o webrtc2sip-mp_session_av.o webrtc2sip-mp_wrap.o webrtc2sip-mp_db_sqlite.o webrtc2sip-sqlite3.o webrtc2sip-mp_db.o webrtc2sip-mp_db_model.o webrtc2sip-jsoncpp.o webrtc2sip-ActionConfig.o webrtc2sip-AudioResampler.o webrtc2sip-DDebug.o webrtc2sip-MediaContent.o webrtc2sip-MediaSessionMgr.o webrtc2sip-Msrp.o webrtc2sip-ProxyConsumer.o webrtc2sip-ProxyPluginMgr.o webrtc2sip-ProxyProducer.o webrtc2sip-SafeObject.o webrtc2sip-SipCallback.o webrtc2sip-SipEvent.o webrtc2sip-SipMessage.o webrtc2sip-SipSession.o webrtc2sip-SipStack.o webrtc2sip-SipUri.o webrtc2sip-SMSEncoder.o webrtc2sip-Xcap.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib  -L/usr/local/lib -ltinySAK   -L/usr/local/lib -ltinyNET   -L/usr/local/lib -ltinyHTTP   -L/usr/local/lib -ltinySIP   -L/usr/local/lib -ltinyDAV   -L/usr/local/lib -ltinySDP   -L/usr/local/lib -ltinyBFCP   -L/usr/local/lib -ltinySIGCOMP   -L/usr/local/lib -ltinyMEDIA   -L/usr/local/lib -ltinyXCAP   -L/usr/local/lib -ltinySMS   -L/usr/local/lib -ltinyMSRP   -L/usr/local/lib -ltinyRTP   -L/usr/local/lib -ltinyIPSec   -lxml2 -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: webrtc2sip-sqlite3.o: undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Edit:

I have tried following option in `Makefile` but no luck :(

```
LDFLAGS= -ldl
```

Comment: The library chain in the posted code is unnecessarily complex.  the simplification would be: '-LpathToLibs followed by '-l for each library to be used from that 'pathToLibs'   I.E. there is no need to repeat the same -L parameter over and over

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution:

Finally find it, used following option and it works!

```
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX CFLAGS='-lpthread' LDFLAGS='-ldl' LIBS='-ldl'
```